# PyQt deconstruct QHttpMultiPart Message

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am connecting to a scanner with PyQt5. The Scanner does its job but I am having problems with the received multipart message at the end.
It contains a QByteArray which contains 3 parts: A json message, a .stl file and a .png image. In the PyQt 4 documentation and in the Qt5 C++ documentation I only find how to construct a multipart message. [PyQt4 QHttpMultiPart Class Reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qhttpmultipart.html) [C++ QHttpMultiPart](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhttpmultipart.html)

Now I wonder how it is possible to deconstruct a multipart message which is stored in a QByteArray? The Header list looks like this:

```
[PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Content-Length'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Content-Type'), PyQt5.QtCore.QByteArray(b'Server')]`
```

And the Multipart Message looks like this:

```
b'--BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 159\r\n\r\n{\n    "lightSensitivity": "High",\n    "meshDensity": "High",\n    "nbFaces": 0,\n    "nbVertices": 0,\n    "scanFormatEncoding": "STL",\n    "state": "finished"\n}\n--BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Length: 84\r\n\r\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00--BOUNDARY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n'
```

Comment: I can likely be wrong, but; QHttpMultiPart is used for *sending*. There are afik no way to read this, in part because it supports direct device read->transmit for large data. Sure you are not looking for http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html or something similar? Also see: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39396

Comment: You don't need qt classes for this: just use the python email package in the stdlib. Start with [email.message_from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html?highlight=message_from_string#email.message_from_bytes), which returns an [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) object.

Comment: @ user3342816 of course the scanner returns a QNetworkreply but the main problem is writing this to the 3 different formats on my harddisk. How can I read these parts from a QNetworkreply (which contains this multipart message as a QByteArray)?